# SAS read input file with following fields

Tags: sas

Hi I have a txt file arranged as follows:

```
ID        Item1            Item2
x1        A                B
x2                         A  
x3        C                D
x4        A                 
x5        A                B
```

There can be blanks in the text file. ID are all unique numbers. I want them read in SAS as follows:

```
ID item
x1 A 
x1 B
x2
x2 C and so on.....
```

Can I do this by infile or is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: What do want output if both ITEM1 and ITEM2 are empty?

Comment: there should be blanks x2 "", x2 "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load `Item1` and `Item2` into an array, iterate & output

```
data want ;
  infile "myfile.txt" ;
  input @1 ID $2. 
        @11 Item1 $1.
        @28 Item2 $1.
        ;

  array items{*} Item1-Item2 ;
  do i = 1 to dim(items) ;
    Item = items{i} ;
    output ;
  end ;

  drop Item1-Item2 ;
run ;
```

Comment: I realized it was not an intelligent question to ask. The solution is straightforward enough. Thanks so much!